# How do i tell if a Bluetooth device is connected to windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

So i have a serial over Bluetooth device that seems to work just fine with my phone, but i cant get it to do the right things on windows 7. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. But at the moment, i really want to achieve one really simple thing. **How can i tell if it is connected to the computer?**

From a look at the Bluetooth properties the closest i can find is this:

[image]

Which is yesterday, but i cant tell if this is correct. It doesnt clearly say connected or disconnected anywhere. I cant read serial from it but i can seem to search it for provided services.

*Bonus question: Is there an application that handles bluetooth devices and isnt the terrible windows 7 devices interface?*